# wget output & error to standard output/standard error

Tags: bash, wget

I wanted to run a simple wget to display the return of a REST call on the terminal, avoiding the long tedious output. I'm using:

```
$ wget -qO- localhost:8080/product/4
{"id":4,"name":"Spoon","price":2}
$
```

Good. However, if there's an error (e.g. 404 - NOT FOUND) it doesn't show anything:

```
$ wget -qO- localhost:8080/badurl/4
$                <- nothing shown...
```

Is it possible to tell wget to show the error in case it happens? Something like:

```
$ wget -qO- localhost:8080/badurl/4
404 - HTTP NOT FOUND
$
```

Maybe I'm asking for too much, but can't hurt asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`man wget`:

> `-nv`
> `--no-verbose`
> Turn off verbose without being completely quiet (use -q for that), which means that error messages and basic information still get printed.

For example:

```
$ wget -nv -O- google.com/doesnotexist
http://google.com/doesnotexist:
2020-09-28 19:57:38 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Comment: Accepted. One extra request, of minor importance: do you know any way of forcing a new line after the content? When sucessful, the response itself (JSON content) doesn't include a CR/LF so the extra line shows up concatenated to it in the same line.